# Jenkins hangs when "Exec command" uses "cmd /c"

Tags: jenkins, ssh, cmd, command

I'm using Jenkins to create a build process.  During the "Build" part of a step I have created a "Send files or execute commands over SSH" block to build a conda environment from an environment.yml file.  To do this I was trying to use a command in the "Exec command" field.  However, whenever I enter a command like `cmd /c "my command here"`, the process hangs forever (or at least until it times out).  I even tried `cmd /c "exit"`, which should just open a terminal and exit immediately and that is hanging forever too.  Anyone have experience with this and can help me figure out how to structure my command so it won't hang?

#### EDIT

[This Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41130) suggests it *might* have something to do with the exit status file.
Not sure if that's helpful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was an option in an advanced section I didn't know was checked that was causing the problem.  In "Send files or execute commands over SSH" / "SSH Publisher" / "Transfers" / "Advanced...", I had the "Exec in pty" checkbox checked, which tries to execute the command in pseudo tty instead of a Windows Command Terminal as I expected.

[image: "Exec in pty" checkbock image]